# Autofac + WCF + self host with windows service using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, windows-services, autofac

I have a several services to host using the netNamedPipeBinding and I chose a Windows Service to host those services. I'm making a simple test trying to query an entity by id, but the return response in all cases is null.

All my services need to use

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,   
                 InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

and I'm thinking that my problem is how I'm injecting my `DbContext` into the container, because the others layers the DI is resolving automatically.

Here is an example of my code:

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RepositoryBase<>)).As(typeof(IRepositoryBase<>)).InstancePerDependency();

```
// and here I'm injecting the implemented classes with their interfaces
// and the same goes to my business classes

// and here is the example of how I'm setting my services
managerBuilder.Register(x => new BusinessManager(x.Resolve<IBusinessppService>()))
                      .As<IBusinessContract>()
                      .InstancePerDependency();

//here is the method where I'm calling to create my service host
private void CreateServiceHost()
{
        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TManager), _baseUri);
        _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TContract), new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), _serviceName);

        var serviceMetadataBehavior = _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

        if (serviceMetadataBehavior == null)
        {
            serviceMetadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            serviceMetadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = false;
            _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetadataBehavior);
        }

        var behavior = _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
        behavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

        _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                                        MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding(),
                                        string.Format("{0}/{1}", _serviceName, "mex"));

        _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new AutomapperServiceBehavior());
        _serviceHost.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior<TContract>(_lifetimeScope);
        _serviceHost.Faulted += _serviceHost_Faulted;
        _serviceHost.UnknownMessageReceived += _serviceHost_UnknownMessageReceived;
        _serviceHost.Open();
}

//and I'm injecting these guys in the constructor
public ServicePublishBase(Uri[] baseUri, ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
{
        _serviceName = typeof(TManager).Name;
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
        _baseUri = baseUri;
}
```

And I have a factory to create all the hosts and the code is like this

```
var pipeBaseUrl = new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/Example/") };

var assemblies = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType());

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .Where(type => type.IsAssignableTo<IServicePublish>())
       .WithParameter("baseUri", pipeBaseUrl)
       .As<IServicePublish>()
       .SingleInstance();

builder.Register(x => new ServicePublishFactory(x.Resolve<IEnumerable<IServicePublish>>()))
       .SingleInstance();
```

For me all this is just fine, all the services is up and running just perfect, but when i make an call to the service its returning me null and i already check the database, the connection string and the endpoint client, all this stuff is fine.

PS: I've already try to use `InstancePerLifetimeScope` but it does not work =(

More examples of my code:
I´m injecting my DbContext like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope()
```

And if I try to resolve manually I get my DbContext back perfectly.
My implementation of the generic repository is like this:

```
public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
{
       return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
}
```

When I call this code there is no exception (like null reference in Context for exemple), that is, the Context was injected.

Example of my client code:

```
var result = client.GetById(1);
```

The result of this call is null and the id = 1 are in the database, I have an text log for debugging and if I log the name of TEntity the name is correct.
Also I'm running an sql profiler and when I call the client nothing is logging in the profiler.

The autofac can't resolve dbcontext in a multithread wcf scenario? Maybe?

Comment: It sounds like everything is getting injected correctly _except_ the `DbContext`. Where do you register that with Autofac? I don't see it above. If you get the container right after you build it, can you resolve the `DbContext` manually? Is there an exception? When you say you call the service and "it's returning you null" - does that mean the service call itself worked but the database isn't returning correctly or that the service never actually received the call to process?

Comment: i´m injecting my DbContext just like this builder.RegisterType<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope()

Comment: It would be good to update the contents of the question with the stuff I mentioned rather than put it here in comments so the registration can be seen in context - e.g., along with the other registrations. Same thing for the answers with the other questions I asked: add that information to the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, i've made the update in the post with the answers of your question, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Well problem solved!
After wasting all my time changing the way i'm injecting the dbcontext and all objects, change the permission in the windows service, change properties in the connection string, after reading a bunch of articles explaining about windows services and permissions when accessing a database i've founded this article wich explain the limitations between the databases.
The database was LocalDb and this type of database has some limitations to run in-process application, and i'm using this database because the team that i'm working with use this db too. I solve this installing a local and full sql server instance.

http://erikej.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html

Special Thanks to [ErikEJ](https://www.blogger.com/profile/12641272161018114573) and Travis Illig